# How to remove data from docker volume?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I prepared Docker image containing libraries needed for building my other project. I want to have a directory /myLibs with libraries from different projects, e.g:

/myLibs:

- projectA
- projectB
- projectC

Dockerfile:

```
FROM my-base:1.0
VOLUME /myLibs
COPY projectA/bin/*.so* /myLibs/projectA/bin/
CMD /bin/bash
```

Built:

```
docker build -t my-libs:1.0 .
```

Then I want to update libs in this image every time when I rebuild projectA. So I prepared Dockerfile:

```
FROM my-libs:1.0  # I changed parent image, because /myLibs/projectB and /myLibs/projectC should remain
VOLUME /myLibs
RUN ls -al /myLibs && rm -rf /myLibs/projectA && ls -al /myLibs
RUN ls -al /myLibs
COPY projectA/bin/*.so* /myLibs/projectA/bin/
CMD /bin/bash
```

As a result I have old projectA libs in my volume:

```
Step 4 : RUN ls -al /myLibs && rm -rf /myLibs/projectA && ls -al /myLibs
 ---> Running in 1e3e25084e69
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jul 16 13:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 75 root root 4096 Jul 16 13:52 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Jul 16 13:51 projectA
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 16 13:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 75 root root 4096 Jul 16 13:52 ..
 ---> d5973da5965c
Removing intermediate container 1e3e25084e69
Step 5 : RUN ls -al /myLibs
 ---> Running in 1d93575b50c2
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jul 16 13:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 75 root root 4096 Jul 16 13:52 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Jul 16 13:51 projectA
---> 6d2a48a5b67b
```

How can I remove files from volume?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the files on rebuild, you probably don't want to do it in the volume. The volume is generally for data you *want* to persist. Remember the volume mounting will occur *after* the container builds, so what's probably happening is the volume with the old data is mounting over any changes you are making in the image (re)build.

What are you using `/myLibs` for? If they are read-only files you want to set up in the build, you might be better off not using a volume and make them part of the image. If you want to modify them, it's probably better to manage that after the build - there is no real reason to rebuild the image if you are just changing files in a networked volume.

Comment: I tried using directory in image instead of volume, but result is the same. If I have e.g. my-libs:1.0 containing  /usr/share/myLibsFromProjectA/, then I cannot rebuild it (using my-libs as the parent of new my-libs), removing this directory. 

I want to put in the image the latest version of my read-only files, so maybe there is no need to rebuild the image each time indeed. But I don't know how to realise it. Could you help?

Comment: This is not an answer, its a comment